# Learning probability from Zero level

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

How do i develop a very good conception in probability theory to do advanced theoretical research in communication theory?Which book do i follow to gain a solid conception about the subject.I have the original manuscript of A N Kolmogorov but do not have the mathematical background to understand it. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For a basic working knowledge of probability, there are many good books such as [An Introduction to Probability](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Probability-Introduction-Oxford-Science-Publications/dp/0198532644/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1392473717&sr=8-5&keywords=probability). They will introduce you to the main terminology and to most basic applications of probability.

However, if you want to see the full story, that is, proofs of most theorems and a real understanding of why things work the way they do, you would have to study a field of mathematics called Measure Theory, which deals with the problem of assigning a 'size' to sets.

It is common to consider a basic knowledge of real analysis, such as the one given in the incredible [Understanding Analysis](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Understanding-Analysis-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387950605/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1392474137&sr=8-1&keywords=understanding%20analysis) to be a prerequisite for studying measure theory, but you might have a go at [Measure, Integral and Probability](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Integral-Probability-Springer-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1852337818/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1392473901&sr=8-1&keywords=measure%20theory) and see how you do. Kolmogorov is usually very mathematically intense, so I'd recommend you to save him for when you're better acquainted with the basics.